# How to write "Example 1.1." in a maths notes style

Tags: math-mode

I don't quite know how to write "Example 1.1" in the style shown below - I need the syntax for writing in the style shown below.

[image: example]

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [tutorial](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Theorems_and_proofs) on Overleaf has exactly what you want.

Namely, you can add

```
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
```

to your preamble. You can then use it as such in the actual document:

```
\begin{example}
The following are examples of meromorphic functions in the complex plane: 
\end{example}
```